# Is a wizard the best design pattern for this problem?

Tags: forms, design-patterns, wizard

So my web app lets users charge monthly subscriptions for email newsletters. In my next update, I am completely retooling the user experience and need some advice. Users can create multiple plans for a newsletter, such as $5 per month, $50 per year, $10 one time charge, etc. Here's the basic flow that every user will need to complete:

1. Enter newsletter info (name, description, etc)
2. Create a plan
3. Create another plan (repeat as desired)
4. Complete process

I was originally going with a wizard because a newsletter needs at least one plan, so I wanted to guide the user to that. However, it is so short that I'm not sure a wizard is the best solution. Is there a better design pattern for this type of problem?

Comment: What does "creating" a plan involve?

Comment: Here is the data I ask for: plan name, amount, frequency (monthly, yearly, etc), currency of the plan, number of trial days. Just a few text fields and a drop-down. The user can create multiple plans, or just one.

Comment: Please show us some work on what you've done.  Pictures of sketches or paper prototypes are fine, it doesn't have to be polished.

Answer (score 1):

Can be one page with all of the inputs needed to create one plan and an ADD PLAN button that for example collapses the first plan and expands UI for creating another plan. Or a hybrid of both.

Would suggest you doing a very rough paper prototype of one page and a wizard with all the information you want your users to give you and all the information you need to share with them and test what people will prefer. One or another approach will depend on what you can technically accomplish and preferences of your users based on amount of inputs/hints/what they are familiar with. And they might give you an insight whether the plans are a fit for them too.

Comment: In my current version I am doing a one-page form and plan creation process, but I was trying to get away from it because I am trying to make my architecture more RESTful. But it may be the best way to do it. I'll mock up some prototypes and interview some users. Thanks!

Comment: You'll see. They might prefer seeing the overall thing and speed of it or will rather continue slower and step by step being given more hints.